# Pairwise comparison; Tukey HSD or FDR

Tags: false-discovery-rate, tukey-hsd-test

I have a general question about running multiple pairwise comparisons. I did some genetic work in grad school, where we (I believe) utilized a statistical test (Student's T-test?) followed by a FDR-adjustment. This seemed to work fairly well at limiting our gathering of false-positives. However, in my current role, in some cases, I end up using Tukey HSD for multiple comparisons (it's especially useful when I wish to categorize groups). As I understand, Tukey HSD also accounts for multiple comparisons.

My question is, when trying to determine what statistical test to perform, is there a good way to know when to use something like a Benjamini-Hochberg control of FDR, and when to perform a test like Tukey HSD? Is there a rule-of-thumb based on how many pairwise comparisons you wish to make, and is one method more sensitive than the other (able to detect differences better, but more-likely to detect false-positives)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

TukeyHSD controls the FWER (the chance of committing ONE or more false positive).

Whereas FDR procedures control for how many discoveries are likely to be false positives (often expressed as a percentage). E.g. 5% of the discoveries are likely to be false positives.

Because genetic analyses typically have many tests, FWER is normally considered inappropriate since there is probably going to be at least ONE Type I error; and this will likely cause missed *leads*.

In essence, FWER is overly strict for so many tests combined with the nature of genetics research, which typically involves looking for genes to further research (rather than strict/absolute findings).

Also, I may recommend using Welsh's unequal variance over Student's T-test.

https://www.statisticshowto.com/false-discovery-rate/

http://daniellakens.blogspot.com/2015/01/always-use-welchs-t-test-instead-of.html

Comment: Ah, thank you, this is great info to have.